# Character Classes in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

I have a question about using regexes in Vim.

When using character classes, if I search using the pattern `[a-y]` the search is case insensitive.

But the pattern `a-z` seems to make the search case sensitive.

I think it's because of the `z`. But I don't know why.

[image]

[image]

And I am using gVim 7.4 on Win 8.1.

[image]

And the character `z` of `[a-z]` is a lowercase `z`

[image]

Changing the pattern to `a-Z` makes the search case sensitive too.

With the pattern `a-Y`, strangely a 'wrong scope' error occurs.

The following images are descriptions about encoding and config.

[image]

[image]

Thanks, everyone. :)

Comment: The output seems correct..what's the problem??

Comment: In the first one you are trying to do `case insensitive search` from `[a-y]` so all the text is selected. In the second one you are trying to do `case sensitive` search for the class `[a-z]`, so only the first sentence is selected. It is not the whole sentence that is selected but it is each character of the sentence that is being selected

Comment: i can reproduce this. Looks like a bug to me (or some particularity, that isn't documented).

Comment: I cannot repro in my gVim 7.4 on Win7, all work as expected. Is the `y` really `y`?

Comment: Yes. plain 7.4 with no patches on Windows, can't reproduce this with 7.4.1261. And yes, it was plain ascii characters only. So this was probably fixed with some patch

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward answer is that in one search, case-sensitivity is on, and in the other, it is not. See `:help 'ignorecase`.

If that is not the case, then the only way I can reproduce this is to use a character that looks like an ASCII `z` but is in reality a completely different character. Among characters that resemble an ASCII `z`, the only one I can find that reproduces this behavior is U+0396 Greek Capital Letter Zeta: `Ζ`.

[image]

[image]

Even this theory is a little shaky, as this character looks like an uppercase `Z`, not a lowercase `z` - at least on my screen.

It is difficult to be certain that this is the issue given only the screenshots above and your description. More information in your question about exactly how you are entering the search characters, what encoding you are using, what your keyboard layout is, etc., might help someone write a better answer than this one.

Comment: Thank you. But i cannot check more information now. Because i am not at home. I will posting after check more information ASAP.:)